# How do I deploy Django app to (AWS) domain name?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, deployment

I've only been working with Django for a few weeks, and just learned deployment. I have an AWS EC2 Instance, which I'm able to deploy my Django website/app to (i.e., if I go to the IP address in my browser, I'm able to access my website). However, I can't figure out how to deploy that same website to my domain name, which is registered on AWS.

I followed AWS's documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html), and https://cachecheck.opendns.com/ shows that my domain name routes to my EC2 instance. However, when I go to my domain name in my browser, it shows a 400 Bad Request. Is there something else I need to do when I setup nginx or gunicorn? I've tried replacing the `{{yourEC2.public.ip}}` in the nginx code to be my domain name instead of the IP address.

I haven't been able to find any other resources online regarding deployment to domain names, specifically with AWS.

This is what I have for deploying to the EC2 instance:

`settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['{{yourEC2.public.ip}}']
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
(venv) ubuntu@54.162.31.253:~myRepoName$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

**gunicorn**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/{{repoName}}
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/{{repoName}}/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 
unix:/home/ubuntu/{{repoName}}/{{projectName}}.sock 
{{projectName}}.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name {{yourEC2.public.ip}};
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/{{myRepoName}};
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/{{myRepoName}}/{{projectName}}.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you create a record set in Route53, either a A record to ip address or CName to the public domain name of EC2 instance?

Comment: @Ashan: Yeah, I created a record set and set the value to be my EC2 instance/IP address.

@Selcuk: Yeah, my Django app/website shows up if I type in my IP address. It just doesn't work when typing in the domain name. I will try setting the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem, and actually found your various posts also seeking solutions. Funny how we both had the exact same issue in such a similar window of time.

I did three things:

- First, I updated my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` just as Selcuk noted:

  - `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['12.345.67.890', 'sub.domain.com', 'www.sub.domain.com']`
- Then, I also edited the `server_name` setting in my nginx configuration:

  - `server_name 12.345.67.890 sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;`
- Lastly, I restarted nginx and rebooted the machine to make sure it all worked:

  - `sudo service nginx restart`
  - `sudo reboot`

After this, I was able to load my domain and the application would load. I know you already found your solution, but wanted to formalize this, as I found your question on StackOverflow and hopefully others will too so they may be spared!

Comment: I was running desperate. Thank you. I would recommend to include the `http` and `https` urls in `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`.

Answer (score 1):

You should set [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) to your hostname(s), such as `['example.com', 'www.example.com']`:

> A list of strings representing the host/domain names that this Django site can serve. This is a security measure to prevent HTTP Host header attacks, which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations.