# unable to access django website from URL but accessible from IP address

Tags: django, nginx, web-hosting, amazon-lightsail

I have installed django on Amazon lightsail, I can access my website through the static server IP address. My domain is hosted on Godaddy. I change the Name Server in GoDaddy. But still when I try to access my website through domain name it shows me Nignx welcome page.

*Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
Thank you for using nginx.*

In my django settings.py I have given only the IP address

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['YOUR_AMAZON_LIGHTSAIL_IP']
```

And in Nginx file, I also added only the IP address.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name YOUR_AMAZON_LIGHTSAIL_IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/django_project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/django_project/django_project.sock;
    }
}
```

I am using Gunicorn and Nginx on my hosting server.

Comment: In ALLOWED_HOSTS the domain name also should be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deploy Django app to (AWS) domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741707/how-do-i-deploy-django-app-to-aws-domain-name)

Answer (score 1):

I did the following changes to allow the domain to work,

1. First create a static IP address on AWS light sail
2. Assign the static IP address to your VPS
3. Create a DNS zone, add the NameServer to your domain provider. In my case its Godaddy.
4. In the django settings.py add the domain name in allowed host setting,

   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', '0.0.0.0']
5. In the Nginx file add the domain name

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name example.com 0.0.0.0;

   ```
   location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
   location /static/ {
       root /home/ubuntu/django_project;
   }

   location / {
       include proxy_params;
       proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/django_project/django_project.sock;
   }
   ```

   }
6. Restart the Nginx

   sudo service nginx restart
7. Restart the server

   sudo reboot

Comment: `server_name` does not interfere with your domain address working or not. And you should not use _0.0.0.0_ in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. When you have fixed IP, use that one. _0.0.0.0_ means it allows all IP.

Comment: o.o.o.o is just for a sample IP address. In reality you will use your server public or static IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the domain name into allowed hosts like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.name']
```

With this users can only access the site via your domain address. If you also want them to be able to access through the IP you do like this

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.name','ip.ip.ip.ip']
```

Comment: domain name I have to give with http://example.com or just example.com?

Comment: @Waqas I don't understand your question. You wrote same twice.